# Add text row in php after submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, click

```
<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?= isset($_POST['test']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['test']) : '' ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo 'You entered: ', htmlspecialchars($_POST['test']);
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

After the click i want add new line automatically.

If now I have:

```
You entered: test1
```

After another click my text is 'test2 I have:

```
You entered: test1
You entered: test2
```

After refresh page all over again.

How do I add text after a click?

Comment: If you want the "You entered..." values to persist between clicks, so that you can have more than one of them displayed at once, then you need to store them somewhere (because HTTP is stateless by nature, and values are not preserved between requests by default). For this purpose, it sounds like the Session would be a sensible place to store it. (if you wanted more long-term storage, or for data to be shared between different users of your site, then file or database storage would be more appropriate forms of data persistence).

Comment: My suggestion to use JavaScript for this case.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev that assumes the data doesn't also need to be transmitted to the server for some purpose. The example code above is almost certainly simplified from what's really needed, because otherwise the program would be fairly pointless.

Comment: JavaScript can be used for submit data to server as well. You can use Ajax technique for post data to server and instantly, without page refresh.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes you can, but that's just extra work, and in this case there's no obvious purpose to it, when there's a much quicker solution using the Session.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure what it is you're after exactly, the following (very basic) code sample might serve to help you on your way.

It uses PHP [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), but as highlighted in the comments, there are other ways of data persistence you might want to investigate.

If you want to go with sessions, do read through the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), there are a lot of important details that are not covered by this answer.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?= isset($_POST['test1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['test1']) : '' ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    <input type="submit" name="clear-input" value="clear">
</form>
</body>
<html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['input'][] = $_POST['test1'];
    foreach ($_SESSION['input'] as $input) {
        echo 'You entered: ' . htmlspecialchars($input);
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['clear-input'])) {
    $_SESSION['input'] = [];
}
?>
```

note: *I added a button to (re)start with a clean slate (clear user input).*